# Rsyslog dirCreateMode not working

Tags: linux, rsyslog

In `/etc/rsyslog.conf`i have set the rule

`dirCreateMode 0750` but the automatically new created directories have the following permissions :

`drwx------  (0700)`

So this prevent me from setting `ACL rules` :

```
group::r-x                      #effective:---
group:user:r-x                  #effective:---
```

Comment: Did you miss the $? Should be $DirCreateMode 0750

Comment: @RamanSailopal Thanks a lot, and yes i did miss $, so embarrassed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems as though the user missed out the $ in the config file

Should have been:

```
$DirCreateMode 0750
```